# C programming count number of occurrences?

Tags: c, algorithm

I am working though the C programming book. I have a question in the arrays section (1.6) that says "Let us write a program to count the number of occurrences of each digit, of white space characters (blank, tab, newline) and all other characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count digits, white space, others */

int main()
{
    int c, i, nwhite, nother;
    int ndigit[10];

    nwhite = nother = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        ndigit[i] = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-0];
        else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t')
            nwhite++;
        else
            nother++;
    printf("digits =");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++);
        printf(" %d", ndigit[i]);
    printf(", white space = %d, other = %d\n", nwhite, nother);

}
```

This is the compiling code. If I type 23, enter, 23, enter then ctrl+d it returns "digits = 1044509184, white space = 2, other = 0". Why? What is digits doing?

Comment: `++ndigit[c-0];` --> `++ndigit[c-'0'];`

Comment: I think She is asking, What digits represents for?

Comment: Line 22: `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++);` --> `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)` (P.S. use `-Wall` when you compile your code so you will easily find mistakes like this)

Comment: By adding quotes around the 0 it is now this: "digits = 172454656, white space = 2, other = 0". I don't understand why digits has so many numbers. What do those numbers mean?

Comment: @ColorfulCodes I think you have not corrected the mistake on Line 22 yet. Then the `printf` that prints counts of digits does not print values of array `ndigits`, but `ndigits[10]` instead (because `i=10` after the previous loop). It is just a block of random uninitialized memory and in your case it is `172454656`.

Comment: @YangHanlin Oh shoot, thank you so much! Such a small mistake. I understand what's happening now. Really appreciated.

Comment: @user12986714, want to post that as the answer?

Comment: @ColorfulCodes Please do not **fix** the code in your questions!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-0];
```

This block of code is problematic as it is accessing the array out of bounds (and will cause undefined behaviours).
It should be

```
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            ++ndigit[c-'0'];
```

Notice the difference between `0` and `'0'`. The latter piece of code works as it is guaranteed that number characters are encoded consecutively.